# Comparing and find out which feature has highest shape area in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, select-by-attribute, spatial-query

I need to find out which polygon is having more area by filtering unique ID. the problem is I have 1000 of features which I need to find out highest occupied area for every unique value...

[image: tp find out highest covered area]

since I have 1000 of features I need to do in an automated way instead of finding out manually,  please help me to solve with some Python script or by using field calculator queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a possibility of using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let's assume we have 10 features in *'layer'* accordingly, where each feature has a unique `"Name"` and mutual `"Group"` attributes, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following Query, it is possible to achieve the result

```sql
SELECT
    l.geometry,
    l.MosaicName,
    l.Name,
    MAX(ROUND(st_area(l.geometry), 2)) AS sqm
FROM
    "Layer" AS l
GROUP BY
    l.MosaicName
ORDER BY
    sqm DESC
```

Mind the CRS. Alternatively you can apply `ROUND(st_area(st_transform(l.geometry,*SRID*)), 2)` if you require area in square feets. Therefore, you have to have an *SRID*.

[image: output]

The output Virtual Layer will provide features with the biggest area in square meters in each group accordingly.

Answering @Gobinath's comment, you can `Save As...` a new shapefile going through a common procedure with a Right mouse click over the Virtual Layer.

Comment: **Thank You**, @Taras. I got the results.

Comment: " lol " .........

Comment: No need to be sorry then ... one way to play it in a more fair way would have been to put your completary elements in a comment ...

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using the DB Manager of QGIS.

You choose **Database / Database Manager / Database Manager** then **Virtual Layers / Qgis Layers** you can then try queries like the following :

```
select area, max(st_area(geometry)) from your_layer_name
group by area_id
```

You have to adapt the attribute's name according to your data structure...

You can then load the result in QGIS layer manager.

Comment: Thanks @snaileater, It works for me but I have a little issue I would like to save as new shape-file (which I queried)  with all columns. The issue is it only returning the two column so How do I do that ?